# Not able to read data from Kafka by Pyspark readStream

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-kafka, spark-structured-streaming

I am trying to read data from kafka topic to my local machine using pyspark readStream.
I am able to correctly printSchema just not able to see the data in readable format.

I am using avaro format schema. I have also checked proper packages I am using them correctly. I have build my own package with maven which you can see a core-snapshot package. for that I have used `spark-core_2.12:3.1.2`

```
spark = SparkSession \
    .builder \
    .appName("Python Spark SQL basic example") \
    .config("spark.jars",
"jar/JavaSpark-1.0-CORE-SNAPSHOT.jar,
jar/spark-streaming-kafka-0-10_2.12-3.1.2.jar,
jar/spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12-3.1.2.jar,jar/kafka-clients-2.6.0.jar,
jar/spark-token-provider-kafka-0-10_2.12-3.1.2.jar,
jar/spark-avro_2.12-3.1.2.jar").getOrCreate()
```

Below is my code to read the data from the stream.

```
.... kafka connection ....

ds1 = spark.readStream.format("kafka").option(<<--rest of kafka connection options-->>).load()

schema_String = '''{
    "fields": [
      {
        "name": "id",
        "type": "string"
      },
      {
        "name": "name",
        "type": "string"
      },
      {
        "name": "age",
        "type": "double"
      },
      {
        "name": "address",
        "type": "string"
      }
    ],
    "name": "person_info",
    "type": "record"
}'''
output = ds1.select(from_avro("value", schema_String).alias("user")).select("user.*")
output.printSchema()
output.writeStream.format("console").start()
```

If I just try to run this.
I am able to see the schema. but not able to see any value. Instead can see a error

```
KafkaOffsetReaderConsumer: Error in attempt 1 getting Kafka offsets: 
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.spark.kafka010.KafkaConfigUpdater.setAuthenticationConfigIfNeeded(KafkaConfigUpdater.scala:60)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.ConsumerStrategy.setAuthenticationConfigIfNeeded(ConsumerStrategy.scala:61)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.ConsumerStrategy.setAuthenticationConfigIfNeeded$(ConsumerStrategy.scala:60)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.SubscribeStrategy.setAuthenticationConfigIfNeeded(ConsumerStrategy.scala:102)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.SubscribeStrategy.createConsumer(ConsumerStrategy.scala:106)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaOffsetReaderConsumer.consumer(KafkaOffsetReaderConsumer.scala:82)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaOffsetReaderConsumer.$anonfun$partitionsAssignedToConsumer$2(KafkaOffsetReaderConsumer.scala:533)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaOffsetReaderConsumer.$anonfun$withRetriesWithoutInterrupt$1(KafkaOffsetReaderConsumer.scala:578)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
    at org.apache.spark.util.UninterruptibleThread.runUninterruptibly(UninterruptibleThread.scala:77)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaOffsetReaderConsumer.withRetriesWithoutInterrupt(KafkaOffsetReaderConsumer.scala:577)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaOffsetReaderConsumer.$anonfun$partitionsAssignedToConsumer$1(KafkaOffsetReaderConsumer.scala:531)
    at org.apache.spark.util.UninterruptibleThreadRunner.runUninterruptibly(UninterruptibleThreadRunner.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaOffsetReaderConsumer.partitionsAssignedToConsumer(KafkaOffsetReaderConsumer.scala:531)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaOffsetReaderConsumer.fetchEarliestOffsets(KafkaOffsetReaderConsumer.scala:293)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaMicroBatchStream.$anonfun$getOrCreateInitialPartitionOffsets$1(KafkaMicroBatchStream.scala:148)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:189)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaMicroBatchStream.getOrCreateInitialPartitionOffsets(KafkaMicroBatchStream.scala:145)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaMicroBatchStream.initialOffset(KafkaMicroBatchStream.scala:73)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.$anonfun$constructNextBatch$5(MicroBatchExecution.scala:392)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:189)
.....
```

If I try to run same thing with

```
output.writeStream.format("console").start().awaitTermination()
```

Then I am not able to see any error but I see something like this.

```
NetworkClient: [Consumer clientId=consumer-spark-kafka-source-3e718355-6963-4f4b-837c-048c53ffb8a0-963583285-driver-0-1, groupId=spark-kafka-source-3e718355-6963-4f4b-837c-048c53ffb8a0-963583285-driver-0] Bootstrap broker broker--address--:port (id: -1 rack: null) disconnected

-- same message repeatedly after every second --
```

Comment: Unclear what Avro data is in your topic, but `spark-avro` & `from_avro` cannot process Schema Registry serialized Avro data

Comment: @OneCricketeer I also tried to send avro schema as string format. still the error remain the same. Can you share some example about serialised avro-data

Comment: Avro is binary, there is no such thing as "string format Avro" unless you mean you converted it to JSON. You've not shared your producer code, so its unclear how you serialized it, but if it was using Confluent libraries, then start here for the consumer https://github.com/AbsaOSS/ABRiS

Comment: I am producing message by REST API to kafka topic. I want to read the data from that topic. I tried using ABRis plugin too. Still the error remain the same. 
```KafkaOffsetReaderConsumer: Error in attempt 1 getting Kafka offsets: ```

Comment: Well, without seeing the actual Kafka Producer code, it'd be hard to help answer what the issue is. If you're using the Confluent REST Proxy, then that uses the Schema Registry, which like I said, the `spark-avro` library does not support. Can you [edit] your post with the AbsaOSS code you tried?